# Unexpected type 'StandardButton' PyQt5 messagebox

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to just have one messagebox to pop with only the option to click 'ok'.

This is the code:

```
show_message_box(QMessageBox.Critical,
                 "ERREUR",
                 "Il n'est pas possible de bloquer cette plage horraire pour " + employee, QMessageBox.Ok)
```

i'm having error `setInformativeText(Self,str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'StandardButton'`

My other msgbox works fine, but they have `yes`, or `no` options. This one, I just want the `ok` option.

Thank you for your help

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.error_popup()

    def error_popup(self):
        
        employee = 'Name 1'
        
        QMessageBox.critical(
            self,
            "ERREUR",
            f"Il n'est pas possible de bloquer cette plage horraire pour <b>{employee}</b>", 
            QMessageBox.Ok
        )
                 
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

[image]